# Count number of comparison made by HeapSort in C#

Tags: c#, comparison, heapsort

I would like to know how I can count the number of the comparisons made by the HeapSort I got on rosettacode? I tried to count it by adding a variable and each time the comparison method gets called this variable gets incremented. But somehow I dont get the right results. I think I have to override the comparison method somehow and use a getter and setter to increment a count variable. A hint will be highly appreciated...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


public class Program
{
    public static void HeapSort<T>(T[] array)
    {
        HeapSort<T>(array, 0, array.Length, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public static void HeapSort<T>(T[] array, int offset, int length, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        HeapSort<T>(array, offset, length, comparer.Compare);
    }

    public static void HeapSort<T>(T[] array, int offset, int length, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        int count = 0;
        // build binary heap from all items
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            T item = array[offset + i]; // use next item

            // and move it on top, if greater than parent
            while (index > 0 &&
                comparison(array[offset + (index - 1) / 2], item) < 0)
            {
                int top = (index - 1) / 2;
                array[offset + index] = array[offset + top];
                index = top;
            }
            count++;
            array[offset + index] = item;
            //Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // delete max and place it as last
            T last = array[offset + i];
            array[offset + i] = array[offset];

            int index = 0;

            // the last one positioned in the heap
            while (index * 2 + 1 < i)
            {

                int left = index * 2 + 1, right = left + 1;

                if (right < i && comparison(array[offset + left], array[offset + right]) < 0)
                {
                    if (comparison(last, array[offset + right]) > 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    array[offset + index] = array[offset + right];
                    index = right;

                    //Console.WriteLine("1st if ");

                }
                else
                {

                    if (comparison(last, array[offset + left]) > 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    } 
                    count++;

                    array[offset + index] = array[offset + left];
                    index = left;

                    //Console.WriteLine("2nd if ");

                }
            }
            array[offset + index] = last;

            //Console.WriteLine("\nRun");
            //for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            //    Console.WriteLine(array[j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe case needed " + count + " comparisons!");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // hardcoded arrays according to the assignment
        int[] arrOne = { 503, 087, 512, 061, 908, 170, 897, 275, 653, 426, 154, 509, 612, 677, 765, 703 };
        int[] arrTwo = { 908, 897, 765, 703, 677, 653, 612, 512, 509, 503, 426, 275, 170, 154, 087, 061 };
        int[] arrThree = { 4, 7, 2, 3 };
        int[] arrFour = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
        int n = 0;
        string c = String.Empty;

        // the application runs until the user agrees to quit at the end of a sorting run
        do
        {
            // displays the 4 arrrays
            Console.WriteLine("Assignment: Given are 4 different arrays; You have the choice which one you want to sort.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n1. Knuths entry sequence:\n   503,087,512,061,908,170,897,275,653,426,154,509,612,677,765,703");
            Console.WriteLine("\n2. Knuths entry sequence descended:\n   908,897,765,703,677,653,612,512,509,503,426,275,170,154,087,061");
            Console.WriteLine("\n3. Just one number:\n   300");
            Console.WriteLine("\n4. A set of 0 and 1:\n   0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0");
            Console.WriteLine("\n Which array do you want to sort?");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            // creating an comparer instance
            //var comp = new CountingComparer<int>();
            Console.Clear();

            switch (n)
            {
                case 1:
                    HeapSort(arrOne);
                    DisplayArray(arrOne);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    HeapSort(arrTwo);
                    DisplayArray(arrTwo);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    HeapSort(arrThree);
                    DisplayArray(arrThree);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    HeapSort(arrFour);
                    DisplayArray(arrFour);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nArray does not exist!");
                    break;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("\nThe case needed " + comp.Count + " comparisons!");
            Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to quit the application? (y/n) ");
            c = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

        }
        while (c != "y");
    }

    public static void DisplayArray(int[] arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted Array!\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("   " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `count++` after the first comparison in your while loop.

Comment: I put it in but still get wrong results... with the first array its supposed to be 85 comparisons. I have tried several things already but dont get this result...

Comment: What are you getting when it is supposed to be 85?

Comment: And post your comparison method, too.

Comment: He's using `Comparer<T>.Default`. Just ran code, and I was wrong. Missing a lot of count++'s, not just the one.

Comment: I get 56 with the first array... and yes I use the Default Comparer, but there must be a way to overide the Compare method by adding a count variable with a get and set method?!

Comment: Or I just write a custom Comparer class with the count variable but than I have to create an instance of it and use this instead of the default ones...

Answer (score 0):

I think doing the count in the compare method is a good idea. Here's a quick and dirty way:

```
public class Program
{
  public static int Count = 0;
  public static int MyCompare<T>(T first, second)
  {
    Count++;
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(first, second);
  }
  // Update your first sort to use the new compare.
  public static void HeapSort<T>(T[] array)
  {
    HeapSort<T>(array, 0, array.Length, MyCompare);
  }
  // Now all of the rest of your original code inside of Program.
}
```

Set `Count` to 0 before calling the sorts, then read count after the sorting is done. I confirmed that on the first sort, it does get set to 85, like you expect.

Comment: Forgot to include the change to `HeapSort<T>`. Updated.

Comment: ok, I got it working but if I choose the same array a scnd time its always 91... the same with the 2nd array, first its 72 how its said to be and then 91

Comment: ah i just see thats the sorted array whats getting sorted the 2nd time... :) thats why the number is different...